# For iteneration + if statement - bottleneck

Tags: performance

in list I have objects of 1, 2, 3 type and I must every frame refresh next list where I need only type 2 and 3. - via calculating in Vector3..

This statement consume a lot of time and slow down program, is there any next possibility how make it better ?

Thank you

EDIT: type of object has changing every frame according to what is happening on screen - unpredictable.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
   if(object[i].... != type1)
     list.add(object[i]);
}
```

Comment: It will help readers if you post the condition in it's entirety.  It may expose some inefficiency or it may confirm that there is none.  However at the moment we don't have enough information to know.

Answer (score 1):

If this is truly a bottleneck - Create a separate list with only `type2` and `type3` entries and update them without the `!= type1` check.

If the codition changes every frame, maybe you better of having a separate list for every type and update resulting list only from the relevant lists.

Comment: type is changing every frame :-(

Comment: You should add this and other relevant info to the question body.